# How to disble splitting sentences on brackets using Spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, sentence

I have such group of sentences in one shot:

> "(T1) Maple - fell. (T2, T3 & T4) Ash - removal of overhanging limbs
>   from neighbour's trees. (T5) Silver birch - fell. (T6) Conifer -
>   reduce height by approximately 1m and reduce spread by approximately
>   0.5m. (T7) Cherry - crown reduce to inner canopy (approximately 50%). (T8) Oak - crown reduce by approximately 1m overall - Church
>   Knowle
>   Conservation Area"

When I use the following code:

```
sent = nlp(s)
for s in sent.sents:
    print(s)
```

I get output - separation of sentences:

> (T1)
>
> Maple - fell.
>
> (T2, T3 & T4)
>
> Ash - removal of overhanging limbs from neighbour's trees.
>
> (T5)
>
> Silver birch - fell.
>
> (T6) Conifer - reduce height by approximately 1m and reduce spread by approximately 0.5m.
>
> (T7)
>
> Cherry - crown reduce to inner canopy (approximately 50%).
>
> (T8) Oak - crown reduce by approximately 1m overall - Church 
>   Knowle Conservation Area

My question is, how to disable splitting sentences on brackets? At first glance I've tried to change brackets to something else - it worked quite with pipes, but not exactly.

I found [https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer/](http://Spacy%20Sentenizer) - there are 3 default splitting characters (".", "!", "?") so don't know what's the current behavior. How to deal with it? How can I change something with coding other way I'm doing right now?

By the way, I'm, trying to override default sentenizer with code:

```
from spacy.pipeline import Sentencizer
sentencizer = Sentencizer()
sentencizer = Sentencizer(punct_chars=[".", "?", "!", "。"])
```

but get error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Sentencizer'

**EDIT**

I used this code only:

```
sentencizer = nlp.create_pipe("sentencizer")
nlp.add_pipe(sentencizer, before="parser")
```

and got something like this:

(T1) Maple - fell. (

T2, T3 & T4) Ash - removal of overhanging limbs from neighbour's 
trees. (

T5) Silver birch - fell. (

T6) Conifer - reduce height by approximately 1m and reduce spread by approximately 0.5m. (

T7) Cherry - crown reduce to inner canopy (approximately 50%). (

T8) Oak - crown reduce by approximately 1m overall - Church Knowle Conservation Area

EDIT

I tried this trick but not working:

```
def set_custom_boundaries(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == ". (":
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = False
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(set_custom_boundaries, before="parser")
```

**EDIT**

I've found some not very elegant solution. To be clear, this is the required splitting:

> ( T1 ) Maple, fell.
>
> ( T2, T3 & T4 ) Ash, removal of overhanging
>   limbs from neighbour's trees.
>
> ( T5 ) Silver birch, fell.
>
> ( T6 ) Conifer, reduce height by approximately 1m and reduce spread by
>   approximately 0.5m.
>
> ( T7 ) Cherry, crown reduce to inner canopy ( approximately 50% ) .
>
> ( T8 ) Oak, crown reduce by approximately 1m overall, Church Knowle
>   Conservation Area

I've used default `sentencizer` and used this regex for the whole string `s = re.sub("\. ", ".  ", s)`. Additionally, had to remove dots before closing bracket: `s = re.sub('\.\s*\)', ')', s)` because it left `)` alone as a whole sentence in some cases. It works up to now as needed but I may expect some problems for other cases.

Comment: when exactly and where do you want a separation of your sentence????

Comment: I need roughly standard separation (on dots, etc) but without such behavior like splitting within brackers or after brackets in such insonsistent way as above (some short sentences are separated (T7) some not (T8).

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you https://support.prodi.gy/t/adding-custom-attribute-to-doc-having-ner-use-attribute/356/6
Currently it seems to me that the regex is the best option :-/ apparently building custom Sentencizer is not so easy... (probably the same is happening to you - KeyError: ... cant find factory for.. etc etc..